# Is that an "r" in "worship" in a text from 1591?

Tags: writing, early-modern-english, transliteration

I was trying to see how the Spanish word *merced* was translated into English in the 16th century, when I found this entry in a dictionary from 1591 by Richard Percyvall:

[image: worship]

I understand that the second English word is *worship*, but that "r" is written in a different way from the *r*'s in *curtesie* and *pleasure*. In a dictionary of Medieval English I found that *[worship](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED53452)* was indeed a valid form for the word by then, but there were also other forms such as *wurðescipe* and *wrþsipe*, so I wonder if I am properly transliterating the word.

So, is that really an *r* in *worship* or is it another different character?

Comment: Middle English is not my field.  A glance at the University of Michigan Press edition of the ‘Middle English Dictionary shows how the English of that time was still in flux, as I am sure you know.  The start is the word ‘wyeth’ = ‘word’; adjective ‘worthen’.  I shall not go on, interesting as the route leading to ‘worship’.  But I leave that to someone who knows what s/he is talking about.

Comment: There are very different faces used for the different languages....one might guess this dictionary was printed in the Low Countries with whatever type was at hand.

Comment: OT: the Spanish formal *you* is *usted* as a contraction of *vuestra merced*; I was taught this could be translated as *your grace*

Answer (score 168, accepted):

That peculiarly written letter is  called the **R rotunda**

[image: an R rotunda with the appearance of the number 2]

> **[The r rotunda (ꝛ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_rotunda)**, "rounded r", is a historical calligraphic variant of the minuscule (lowercase) letter Latin r used in full script-like typefaces, especially blackletters.
>
> Unlike other letter variants such as "long s" which originally were orthographically distinctive, r rotunda has always been a calligraphic variant, **used when the letter r followed a letter with a rounded stroke towards the right side, such as o, b, p, h** (and d in typefaces where this letter has no vertical stroke, as in ∂, ð). In this way, it is comparable to numerous other special types used for ligatures or conjoined letters in early modern typesetting.

Wikipedia

Comment: Apparently the _rotunda_ (which, until today, I thought was only a kind of building) originates in [Carolingian miniscule - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carolingian_minuscule).

Comment: @Nigel "Rotunda" also means roundabout in Portuguese.

Comment: @PedroLobito "Rotonde" in Dutch

Comment: @NigelJ *minuscule* is so spelled because it is related to *minus*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Congratulations. :)

Comment: Isn't this just a half-R? The one that's used after an O or other character that can act as the leg? I.e. it's not a separate character, just a separate glyph - like the two ways of writing lowercase A.

Comment: Reading your post and the quote more closely, I see you wrote exactly what I said, you're just calling it by a different name. I've been a calligrapher for more years than I care to remember, but I've only ever heard it called a half-R. It occurs in many, many historical hands, not just gothic and Carolingian minuscule. I wasn't aware that it was ever used in printing, but given how early printers were trying to reproduce manuscripts, I suppose it makes sense.

Comment: @Marthaª If you can find a good source which uses "half-R" as the name of the variant, that sounds like a useful addition to edit into the Wikipedia article. :)

Answer (score 29):

After reading more pages of the 1591 dictionary it was made clear that it was an *r*. It is also made clear by reading the text in this image:

[image: Early modern text]

In this image, taken from [this page](https://resobscura.blogspot.com.es/2013/07/why-does-s-look-like-f-how-to-read.html), you can see words such as *more* and *or* written with that type of *r*. As noted in the linked page:

> A variant of the long S is in full effect here,  but so are a number of other features that look unusual to modern readers: capital letters like 'T' or 'H' take elaborate forms, and lowercase 'd' and 'r' retain the look of [Carolingian miniscule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carolingian_minuscule) [sic] or Gothic blacklister, the handwritings of choice of medieval monks.

Now the next question would be why some words were written with the current *r* while others were written with the old-style *r*.

Comment: It's a calligraphic thing. Early printing tried to imitate manuscripts, hence ligatures, abbreviation marks, this half-R, and long S were reproduced faithfully in typography.

Answer (score 9):

I can only help with the way the word 'worship' was printed during the 1500s.

These are the various bible translations of Matthew 4:10 (Thou shalt worship the Lord thy God) from 1175 to 1568. I have highlighted the word 'worship' in its various forms but am unable to say which word it is in the Wessex Gospels of 1175.

The 'r' is included from 1382 up to 1568.

All from [**Textus Receptus Interlinear**](http://textusreceptusbibles.com/Interlinear/40004010)

> Bishops Bible 1568
>   The sayth Iesus vnto hym: Auoyde Sathan. For it is written: Thou shalt **worshyp** the Lorde thy God, and hym only shalt thou serue.
>
> Geneva Bible 1560
>   Then sayd Iesus vnto him, Auoyde Satan: for it is written, Thou shalt **worship** the Lord thy God, and him onely shalt thou serue.
>
> The Great Bible 1539
>   Then sayeth Iesus vnto hym Auoyde Satan. For it is written: Thou shalt **worshyp** the Lorde thy God, and hym onely shalt thou serue.
>
> Matthew's Bible 1537
>   Then sayd Iesus vnto him. Auoide sathan. For it is wrytten, thou shalt **worshippe** the Lord thy God and him only shalt thou serue.
>
> Coverdale Bible 1535
>   Then sayde Iesus vnto hym: Auoyde Sata. For it ys wrytte: thou shalt **worshyp** the LORDE thy God and hym onely shalt thou serue.
>
> Tyndale Bible 1534
>   Then sayde Iesus vnto hym. Avoyd Satan. For it is writte thou shalt **worshyp** ye Lorde thy God and hym only shalt thou serve.
>
> Wycliffe Bible 1382
>   Thanne Jhesus seide to hym, Goo, Sathanas; for it is writun, Thou schalt **worschipe** thi Lord God, and to hym aloone thou shalt serue.
>
> Wessex Gospels 1175
>   Ða cwæð se hælend to him. Gang þu succa on-bæc. Soðlice hit is awriten. to drihtne þine gode þu þe ge-eadmestð (sic). & him ane þeowast.

Comment: It looks like the sentence is written like "to the Lord your God you will worship", so I bet that _ge-eadmestð_ (with an apparent error noted by the _sic_) is the _worship_ verb.

Comment: @Charlie Just how much are you willing to bet ? Or can we find an expert ?

Comment: No, please, find an expert. I said that as a wild guess because Wiktionary says that _[drithen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drihten)_ means _the Lord_. So _to drihtne þine gode_ must be _to the Lord your God_. That leaves us with _þu þe ge-eadmestð_ that must be something like _you will worship_.

Comment: @Charlie I'm only teasing :) I think you may well be correct.

Comment: Bosworth Toller gives *humble, humilliate, worship, ...* for [ge-eádmédan](http://bosworth.ff.cuni.cz/014168)

Comment: Why is the Wycliffe Bible 1382 version the easiest (for me at least) to decipher, shouldn’t the most recent version be the easiest to decipher? For instance, the Wessex Gospels 1175 looks like hieroglyphics to me.

Answer (score 4):

I quote below from OED sense 1, of the noun ***worship***. Its etymology is from the word *worth*, with the ending *-ship*. Although it is not described as of Saxon or Germanic origin, it is clearly of Old English derivation since examples are provided from well before the Norman conquest.

Even at the time of King Alfred there was an r included, though in other respects the spelling is quite different.

By the time of the sixteenth century (the later part of which relates to your query) it is spelled in a variety of ways: *wurship*, *worshype* etc - but always with an r.

The modern spelling of *worship* would appear to be *de rigueur* from about 1600.

> I. The quality or condition of having or deserving honour or high
>   rank, and derived senses.
>       a. The condition (in a person) of deserving, or being held in, high esteem or repute; honour, distinction, renown; good name. Now
>   arch. or hist.See also of (good, great) worship at Phrases 5.
>
> eOE   King Ælfred tr. Boethius De Consol. Philos. (Otho) (2009) I.
>   xxx. 531   Hi wunnon æfter weorðscipe on þisse worulde, and tiolodon
>   goodes hlisan mid goodum weorcum.
>
> OE   West Saxon Gospels: John (Corpus Cambr.) iv. 44   Nan witega næfð
>   nanne wurðscype [OE Lindisf. Gospels uorðscip; L. honorem] on hys
>   agenum earde. c1275  (▸?a1200)    Laȝamon Brut (Calig.) (1963) l. 1578
>   Worðschepe [c1300 Otho worsipe] haue þu þire wel-deda.
>
> c1275  (▸?a1216)    Owl & Nightingale (Calig.) (1935) 1344   An maide
>   mai luue cheose Þat hirewurþschipe ne forleose.
>
> c1330  (▸?a1300)    Arthour & Merlin (Auch.) (1973) l. 8619   On him y
>   told hir wele bitowe So ful y knawe him of worþschipe.
>
> a1375   William of Palerne (1867) l. 551   Þat were semlyest to seye
>   to saue my worchep.
>
> ▸ a1387   J. Trevisa tr. R. Higden Polychron. (St. John's Cambr.)
>   (1865) I. 155   To wynne þe maystrie of wommen þou getest but litel
>   worschippe.
>
> c1430   Compleynt in J. Schick Lydgate's Temple of Glas (1891) App. 63
>   Of worshepe, honour & mesure She is the welle.
>
> 1432   in Paston Lett. (1904) II. 37   The said Erle, that all his
>   dayes hath..desired..to kepe his trouthe and worship unblemysshed.
>
> 1485   Caxton tr. Paris & Vienne (1957) 8   Euery man dyd hys best to
>   gete worshyp there.
>
> 1530   J. Palsgrave Lesclarcissement 418/1   If he wyll say it of his
>   worshyp [Fr. sur son honneur] I dare affyrme it.
>
> 1555   H. Braham Inst. Gentleman Prol. sig. *vjv   Thus most men
>   desyre the title of wurship, but fewe doo worke the dedes that vnto
>   worship apperteigne.
>
> 1600   P. Holland tr. Livy Rom. Hist. xxxv. 900   As many as were of
>   any havoir, worth and worship..fled to the Consull.
>
> 1639   J. Clarke Paroemiologia 99/1   Wealth makes worship.
>
> 1657   Fides Divina 72   How sottish therefore is the practice of all
>   such as attribute any divine esteem, honour, or worship to any man.
>
> a1810   C. B. Brown in W. Dunlap Mem. C. B. Brown (1815) I. 262   The
>   honours of this new Saint, speedily eclipsed those of Arthur the king.
>   The fame and worship of the ancient Arthur, had never travelled much
>   further than the bounds of his own diocese.
>
> 1859   Tennyson Elaine in Idylls of King 216   It will be to your
>   worship, as my knight,..To see that she be buried worshipfully.
>
> 1896   A. C. Swinburne Tale of Balen v. 186   Great worship shall ye
>   win..And look that ye do knightly now, For great shall be your need, I
>   trow.
>
> 1911   Encycl. Brit. XXVII. 105/2   Adventurous knights would travel
>   far afield in time of peace to gain worship in conflicts that perilled
>   life and limb.
>
> 1992   Rev. Eng. Stud. 43 316   The friendship of individual knights
>   out pursuing adventure and ‘worship’.
>
> a2005   R. R. Davies Lords & Lordship (2009) viii. 209   Lords had to
>   prove their worship as much as retainers their service.

Comment: So I suppose then that _worship_ is written in the text with just a different type of _r_, the same way as the _s_ was written with a character that resembled more an _f_.